# Click eventlistener within 'class' referring to a function within that same class is not working

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why this isn't working. The cThis.menuClick doesn't recieve the event, it does get called though.

```
// no event passed to cThis.menuClick
var Menu = new function() {
    var cThis           = this;
    // .....
    cThis.menuItems     = cThis.element.querySelectorAll('#menu-items a.menu-item');

    for(var i=0; i<cThis.menuItems.length; i++) {
        cThis.menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', cThis.menuClick, false);
    }

    cThis.menuClick = function(event, returning) {
        if (event) { event.preventDefault(); }
        // not prevented
    }

}
```

I solved the issue this way:

```
// event passed, working!
var Menu = new function() {
    var cThis           = this;
    // .....
    cThis.menuItems     = cThis.element.querySelectorAll('#menu-items a.menu-item');

    for(var i=0; i<cThis.menuItems.length; i++) {
        cThis.menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', mC, false);
    }
    function mC(event) {
        cThis.menuClick.call(this, event);
    }

    cThis.menuClick = function(event, returning) {
        if (event) { event.preventDefault(); }
        // prevented
    }

}
```

Although this workaround is working, I whould like to know why the first code isn't?
Code is wrapped in a namespace:

```
var NS = new function() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`menuClick` is not defined when the event is attached. Simply assign the function to the `menuclick` property prior to registering it with the event listener.

```
var Menu = new function() {
    var cThis           = this;
    // .....
    cThis.menuItems     = cThis.element.querySelectorAll('#menu-items a.menu-item');

    cThis.menuClick = function(event, returning) {
        if (event) { event.preventDefault(); }
        // not prevented
    }

    for(var i=0; i<cThis.menuItems.length; i++) {
        cThis.menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', cThis.menuClick, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's works. Why does the
    function mC() {
method works assigned after the listener and the
    var menuClick = function() { }
is not ?